# Why is session['logged_in'] == True before logging in?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to redirect users who are logged in to a search page based on `session['logged_in']` and others to a login page, but for some reason `session['logged_in']` is True even before I even log in. What's wrong?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable                                                                      
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):                                                                         
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem                                                                 
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False                                                               
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"                                                             
Session(app)                                                                                                                                                                                                
# Set the secret key                                                                                  
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

# Set up database                                                                                     
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))                                                     
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))      

@app.route('/')                                                                                       
def main():
    if  session.get('logged_in') is True:                                                                     
        return redirect(url_for('search'))                                                                
    else:                                                                                                     
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting (and indentation) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't a session `logged_in` before logging in and it is deleted after logging out You should try :

```
@app.route('/')                                                                                       
def main():
    if session.get('logged_in'):                                                                     
        return redirect(url_for('search'))                                                                
    else:                                                                                                     
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the session, as long as the session lives, the `logged_in=True` lives in it too.
You should provide a `logout` route or somehow, `pop` the `logged_in` from the session.

```
session.pop('logged_in', None)
```

note you should provide the `None` default value, so if a user who is not logged in try's to log-out, you don't get a `KeyError`. with flask, if you try to `pop` a value from the `session` dict and that key doesn't exist, you will get a `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a logout route with a session.pop('logged_in', None) but should I implement a session.pop in the main() even when someone first visits '/'? I tried to throw in a session.pop('logged_in', None) before the @app.route('/') but got a "Working outside of request context" error.

Comment: I think you have a design problem here. you have set `session.permanent ` to False, this should be `True` and you should set a `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` variable in configs. this variable is set to 31 days by default, you should lower it down. every user, with this amount of inactivity, will be logged out(session pop).